# Mysql - choose main item in the Group By

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT codigo, protocolo, status, nome 
    FROM protocolo
    GROUP BY  protocolo.protocolo 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT codigo, protocolo, status, nome 
    FROM simulador
) tabela
```

return

```
codigo  protocolo   status   nome
559     2016000026   1       ALESSANDRO CAMPOS BONIFACIO
0       2016000026   0       ALESSANDRO CAMPOS BONIFACIO
0       2016000008   0       MARIA DE JESUS F. DA SILVA ***
0       2016000007   0       MARGARIDA BORGES DA SILVA
558     2016000008   1       MARIA DE JESUS F. DA SILVA ***
556     2015014035   1       MARIA DALVA DA SILVA
```

There are two identical protocolo (2016000008) with different status (0,1) . I want to display **only one** of the repeated protocolo , one that has status = 1

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Please edit and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT odigo, protocolo, MAX(status) as stat, nome 
FROM (
    SELECT codigo, protocolo, status, nome 
    FROM protocolo
    GROUP BY  protocolo.protocolo 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT codigo, protocolo, status, nome 
    FROM simulador
) tabela
GROUP BY codigo, protocolo, nome ;
```

Note: In a `GROUP BY` query, all columns in the `SELECT` should be either in the `GROUP BY` or in aggregation functions, unless you really, really know what you are doing.